# sqlalchemy CTE - mirroring a table and pushing data into it

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, common-table-expression

The following question is someway technical and someway performance oriented...

I have in `MySQL` a `user` table (as described bellow).
In a normal scenario `user`s data is being saved into the database and going through a long process of validations and enrichment that rely heavily on sqlalchemy.

In the new scenario I want to run the data through the same process but without saving it.
I see 2 main options:

1. creating a temp table that is identical and injecting it into the process.
2. working with `cte` (which I just bump into for the first time).

For my understanding working with `cte` should provide better performance.

My questions is:

- can I create an empty `sqlalchemy` `cte` object which has the same structure of the existing table and push data into it?
- can I query this `cte` object as if it was a regular `sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query` object?

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(INT, primary_key=True)
    first = Column(CHAR(50))
    last = Column(CHAR(50))
```

Comment: using option 1, has also some challenges along the way...    in the process I'm work with a Declarative object. so after creating the temp table I will need to map a new Declarative object to it which looks the same as the original Declarative and inject it in to the process